# Where do I find QGIS QML schema?

Tags: qgis, qml

I have a set of GeoPackages created with QGIS. They have those `layer_styles` in it, which contain -- among other columns -- the `styleQML` column providing styling information.

I am reading and manipulating such GeoPackages with GeoPandas, and one of the actions I'm applying is renaming: renaming layers and columns in some layers -- to apply a naming convention of our project. Eventually, the new geopackage(s) will be saved to a new `.gpkg`.

My problem is with QGIS' `styleQML` content we found in `layer_styles`: QML is a XML document. I want to know what is the schema/model `styleQML` follows so that I can write a modifier (for whenever I change the name of layer/column, changes are properly applied to `styleQML`).

Comment: I don't believe there is one

Comment: Apparently not indeed...

Comment: Don't forget the column name could be part of an expression (rule based styling, labels etc) and could be written in different ways (with / without a doublequote)